# $A = Pe^{rt}$? How do I properly calculate this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, I have a word problem that I need to use the formula $A = Pe^{rt}$ to solve...

Suppose $2000 is invested at an interest rate 2.75% compounded continuously. What is the balance in the account after 4 years? Round answer to the nearest cent.

I know that...
$$
P = \$2000\\
R = 2.75\%\\
T = 4
$$

What I'm trying to do is calculate this using my TI-83 and I believe the way to do this is by first multiplying 2.75(4), then press the $e^x$ button, plug in my answer, then multiply it by $2000$. That's my understanding of it, but what's the actual *correct* way to insert this problem into my calculator?

Comment: You wrote 2.75% above, but 2.78 in the description. Also, you need to make sure of precedence and that can vary on different implementations (and calculators). Is your equation p*(e^r)*t or p*e^(r*t)- as this makes a huge difference. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Amzoti said, I think correct eqn is $A=Pe^{rt}$

you can plot

`y=2000*e^(.0275x)`

in a graph and use the 2nd Calc- Value commands to evaluate at $t=4$, or can use 2nd Table to check your for multiple ranges of $t$ (we just use $x$ in the ti-83).

the way you did it should be totally fine too, so long as you use the right formula.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I tried it both ways and came up with the same answer. :)